# Updating web.config with an MSBUILD task

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, web-config, web-deployment-project, fileupdate

I'm using an Web Deployment project to do a few post build tasks on a website I'm deploying.

I want to use a FileUpdate task to update my web.config and change the compilation mode from `debug="true"` to `debug="false".`

So, from this

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#"
                 debug="true" />
```

To this

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#"
                 debug="false" />
```

My FileUpdateTask looks like this

```
<FileUpdate Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'"
                Files="$(Configuration)\Web.Config"
                Regex="debug=\"true\""
                ReplacementText="debug=\"false\"" />
```

but that is completely invalid as you can't escape a quote in XML.

How else can I match the debug attribute in the Regex and have a valid ReplacementText value?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

either use the XmlUpdate task from [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) or try a regex of:

```
Regex="debug=&quot;true&quot;"
```